# using a text string as mini database with linq

Tags: c#, linq

i need help and direction .
im trying to use a delimited text string as minidatabase,
it for use in a game that uses a limit version of c# as ingame scripting language.

im a complete newbie to c# and linq ..so write slowly and clear and loud  pls:)

okay ...the enviroment :
i only have access to these usings(even some of the methods contained are prohibited dont know which exactly):

```
using System;
using System.Linq ;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

to store the delimited text i have just one string variable it gets saved or restored on server reboots and stuff like that.

the code itself you can write ingame gets executed once, until it gets called again similar to a phpscript on a webserver.

so my idea is to use csv like string for storage like so:

```
string db_txt ="testdb1|testtable1|fieldname=test|fieldname=test|fieldname=test;" +
               "testdb1|testtable1|fieldname=test|fieldname=test|fieldname=test;" +
               "testdb2|testtable1|fieldname=test|fieldname=test|fieldname=test;" +
               "testdb2|testtable2|fieldname=test|fieldname=test|fieldname=test;";
```

now i need a way to get linq to make me  nested arrays or dicionarys
to get and set the stored data and turn the entire thing back into a
string to save on programm end.

it should have the database->table->rows->fieldname value structure.

i would be nice if the resulting structure where accessable with relative uncomplicated linq querys to get set rows and values.

or mybe someone has a better idea alltogether to archiv this.

i allready broke me fingers with linkpad..thats the result:

```
var db_lines = db_text.Split(';').Select(x=>x.Split('|')).ToArray();

var result =  from x in db_lines group x by x[0] into dbs_g 
         select new {dbname = dbs_g.Key,
                     tables =(from tab in dbs_g group tab by tab[1] into rows_g
         select new {tablename = rows_g.Key ,rows = rows_g}
         };
```

this gives a similar structure to what i need but i dont really know what im doing with this.

i know there are similar questions here posted allready but they dont helped me to understand how to do this.

any ideas anyone?

Comment: Just for starters, I'd use a Dictionary, if you're dead-set against using a legit DB (which you SHOULD do). Linq is built, basically to translate SQL query results into hashed (i.e., dictionary, basically) values. Save your Dictionary to a local JSON file, and read from it.

Comment: What exactly is the issue and what is your question? If that gives you what you need, then what do you need help with?

Comment: May I ask why you use C# for scripting at all?

Comment: Why not use standard csv? There are already libraries available to load it up and query it with linq.

Comment: Linq has 2 forms and you are using (mixing) both. Start with `db_text.Split(';').Select(x=>x.Split('|').ToArray()).ToArray();` and you have a `string[][]` with your data. You can copy that to your own table/row classes with for-loops.

Comment: @GertArnold: The OP will know more, but the first few sentences do not sound as though it was the OP's choice to use C# for scripting.

Comment: okay ill try to lift the confusion  ...i have to use c# for the scripting cause it build into the game as the ingame script language ..im not the developer i just buyed it like any other comptergame i have to use what the devs build into there game , and no i cannot connect to a database or bind one in since its inside a pc game named space engineers , i also cannot ad any usings to the code cause i dont have access to . all i have are the usings stated above  and one single string var as storage. thats the chalenge

Comment: @Filburt: [`DataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) is in the `System.Data` namespace and thus not in the set of available namespaces as per the question.

Comment: @dylanthelion: I suppose you could help the OP by outlining how to use a legit DB or save something to a local JSON file by using only types from the namespaces listed in the question.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: legitimate criticism, though 'how do I save and write a data model in a .NET environment by using JSON and Streamreader" seems like too vague of a question for SO. Honestly I feel like this question should be down voted and deleted, or that the OP should be told to use a SQL DB, which Linq is made to interface with. But I'm not a fan of down voting, so I gave the OP a place to start.

Comment: @dylanthelion: You know that `StreamReader` isn't available, either, if the OP is limited to the indicated set of namespaces, right? Also, you should indeed explain *how* the OP is supposed to use an SQL DB in the described limited environment.

Comment: OP, to get a better image of your environment: Is it possible to add references to external libraries? Maybe just out of interest, is it a "limited C#" (i.e. run on the .NET framework or Mono, with various parts of the runtime library "forbidden"), or is it a "custom C#-lookalike" (i.e. a language based upon C#, but only developed far enough to offer the described small set of runtime features"?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: "how do I jerryrig a DB, using this limited namespace", is a super silly question, and I'm assuming the OP is not a ridiculous idiot. Adding a namespace is easy if you have Intellisense, and if you don't...? I assume the OP just wants to know how to incorporate a model, and has some nascent ideas about how to do so. Do you have an answer? If not, and if I can say so without starting a quarrel, you're not helping by nitpicking.

Comment: @dylanthelion: I'm sorry, I understand the question in such a way that the OP is working in an environment with a very limited excerpt of the standard runtime library. Consequently, it is not a question about whether or not to add a `using` in source code, the issue is that besides the ones listed in the question, no other namespaces *exist*.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: No worries! I've never worked in an environment with limited namespaces, and am approaching this question from the perspective of (where I was some years back) somebody who has a conceptual model, and no idea how to use it. I think we're just approaching this from opposite directions.

Comment: @dylanthelion: I am basing my interpretation upon the statement from the first paragraph, "a game that uses a limit version of c# as ingame scripting language", and the mention that some methods are "prohibited". Both of these statements indicate to me that the OP is severely limited by the target environment they have to work in, not because they chose to use only a limited set of resources. The OP may want to clarify, though, and maybe improve wording in some respects, such as referring to the runtime library/BCL as limited rather than the language C# when the former limitation is focused.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: You're right: I think clarification by the OP is what we need. While it's possible that s/he is limited by their environment, I find it more likely that the OP doesn't have a full knowledge of the relevant classes for model usage in C# (the 'complete newbie' admission is why I'm assuming that). Though you could also be right,

Answer (score 0):

My other answer assumed that you could add additional namespaces. Sorry about that. The namespaces you have to work with are a little limiting so this is a bit of a hacky solution but it's all I can think of at the moment.

You could use classes to hold your database and define methods to convert them to and from strings. Something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        var bread = new Product() { ID = 0, Cost = 1.0m, Name = "bread" };
        var milk = new Product() { ID = 1, Cost = 1.1m, Name = "milk" };
        var item0 = new OrderItem() { ID = 0, Product = bread, Quantity = 2 };
        var item1 = new OrderItem() { ID = 1, Product = milk, Quantity = 3 };
        var order = new Order() { ID = 0, OrderItems = new List<OrderItem>() { item0, item1 } };

        string data = order.ToString();

        Order copy = Order.FromString(data);
    }
}

public class Order
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append(ID);
        builder.Append(';');

        foreach (var item in OrderItems)
        {
            builder.Append(item.ToString());
            builder.Append(';');
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }

    public static Order FromString(string str)
    {
        var values = str.Split(';').ToList();
        int id = int.Parse(values[0]);
        var items = new List<OrderItem>();

        for (int i = 1; i < values.Count-1; i++)
        {
            items.Add(OrderItem.FromString(values[i]));
        }

        return new Order() { ID = id, OrderItems = items };
    }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append(ID);
        builder.Append(',');
        builder.Append(Product.ToString());
        builder.Append(',');
        builder.Append(Quantity);
        return builder.ToString();
    }

    public static OrderItem FromString(string str)
    {
        var values = str.Split(',');
        int id = int.Parse(values[0]);
        Product product = Product.FromStrings(values.Skip(1).ToList());
        int quantity = int.Parse(values[4]);

        return new OrderItem() { ID = id, Product = product, Quantity = quantity };
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", ID, Cost, Name);
    }

    public static Product FromStrings(List<string> strings)
    {
        int id = int.Parse(strings[0]);
        decimal cost = decimal.Parse(strings[1]);
        string name = strings[2];

        return new Product() { ID = id, Cost = cost, Name = name };
    }
}
```

}

Comment: tj again BUT i wanted a linq solution(or as mutch as possible) as stated in my question header the reason for this is a instruction limit of like 50000 instructions all the loops will eat alot of it once the string to parse gets bigger ..linq bypasses that limitation and dont stress stat limit.

Comment: @user3774901: You should add that restriction to your question, where you describe the constraints of your environment. Also please do mention that it's a limit of roughly 50000 *executed* instructions (I figure that's the case from your comment), not of roughly 50000 *written* instructions (in which case loops wouldn't matter).